# File Copying using Exec and Cmd.exe In Innosetup

Tags: cmd, copy, exec, inno-setup

I am trying to find the correct code for file copying from one directory to another using Exec and cmd.exe but could not get any success.

```
Exec('cmd.exe', ' /C copy ,ExpandConstant('{localappdata}\MyApp\MyFile.txt') ,ExpandConstant('{app}' '{\}', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, MyApp_ResultCode)
```

I am not able to set the correct string for source and destination here.

Aim is to copy the file MyFile.txt from localappdata\MyApp folder to -> Current App directory(from where the exe is being run).

Comment: There are some errors in your script - missing `'`, redundant `{\}` Constant and missing closing parenthesis `)`. Should be: `Exec('cmd.exe', ExpandConstant('/C copy {localappdata}\MyApp\MyFile.txt {app}\'), '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, MyApp_ResultCode)`. The `{app}` folder should already exist before copy attempt - if you want to create this folder during the copy operation, then you should use `XCOPY` or additional `MD` command. Of course I do not know your real `MyApp` name, so I have used your example name.

Comment: Raulp, stop using `cmd.exe` from now on. For a long time I'm wondering, why do people tend to execute command prompt when they don't. @RobeN, why do you suggest using command line tools ? There are native functions that you're aware of, to do this task.

Comment: @TLama whats the disadvantage of using it? Btw i have to add a blank argument to above to make it working as it is giving me error of invalid arguments.With blank argument '' i can see it compiling fine .Have to test it !

Comment: Using native functions is better at least because you're not unecessarily executing command prompt, you're not relying on certain command line tools and you can easily determine result of the function calls.

Comment: I agree Native function are much simpler as well! Thnx !

Comment: To be more specific, you should be using either the `FileCopy` code function or an `external`-flagged `[Files]` entry.  Absolutely no reason to do this via the command prompt.  Further note however that you're going to have problems with the above task anyway; if `{app}` is in `{pf}` then you need `PrivilegesRequired=admin`, but if you have that then you're probably going to be copying from the wrong `{localappdata}` in at least some cases.  So your whole requirement is a bit weird.

Comment: In my case {app} is not in {pf} and the the exe is supposed to be run with admin-rights privleges(right click Option)